# What are the types of transcendental functions?

Tags: calculus, functions, transcendental-functions

I was reading through my Calculus Textbook. When I got the chapter on transcendental functions it mentioned how to integrate and differentiate them. The only functions it mentioned were exponential, logarithmic, and trigonometric functions ex{$e^x$,$\log(x)$, and $\sin(x)$}

My question is there other types of transcendental functions, and if so what are they?

Comment: https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales

Answer (score 2):

Transcental functions are all those functions which are not algebraic. There is no way of decribing them all. One example is the gamma function:$$\Gamma(t)=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-x}x^{t-1}\,\mathrm dx.$$Another example is Riemann's zeta function$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^s}.$$But there are lots and lots of other examples. Simpler ones are the hyperbolic sine and the hyperbolic cosine:$$\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2\text{ and }\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2.$$

Comment: So basically functions that can't be written in polynomial form.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar No. $sqrt x$ is algebraic, not transcendental. And so is $\frac 1x$. Basically, it's those functions which cannot be described by algebraic processes only.